# Exposing warnings from nodes using snow

Tags: r, snow

I have an lapply operation that I've parallelised using `snow`. This works fine except that any warnings generated seem to just get ignored and are hence never shown to the user. Is there a way of exposing warnings on individual nodes so they come through in the main R process?

My best idea at the moment is to have all nodes write their warnings to files, and read those at the end, but there must be a better way!

Here's a reprex:

```
library(snow)

f <- function(x){
  warning("mywarning")
  return(NULL)
}

cl <- makeCluster(2, type="SOCK")

lapply(1:2, f)  # Gives me warnings, as desired
clusterApply(cl, 1:2, f)  # Gives me the same output, faster, but with no warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up switching from snow to the `future.apply` package (in conjunction with `parallel`). `future.apply` now has this behaviour by default.

Unfortunately in most cases the messages/warnings don't appear until the whole run has finished, but that's a whole new issue.